# You specified a password in the connection string, but the native SQLite library you're using doesn't support encryption

Tags: forms, xamarin, encryption, passwords, microsoft.data.sqlite

I am facing an issue to set the Password attribute in the Sqlite connection string in Xamarin Forms Android application. It is working fine in Xamarin Forms iOS. I have used the following `

```
connection.ConnectionString = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString)
        { Password = password }
        .ToString();
connection.Open();
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbbfo.png)
You specified a password in the connection string, but the native SQLite library you're using doesn't support encryption.

I am using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 3.1.5 nuget package on my Xamarin Forms application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-sqlcipher

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite nuget package

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite  does not support encryption.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @Jason Please have a look https://www.bricelam.net/2016/06/13/sqlite-encryption.html

Comment: The error message is clear that it does not support encryption.

Answer (score 7):

I know that is later to respond to this question, but the answer can help others to get solution quickly.

Below the solution as [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) has comment above :

```
dotnet remove package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
dotnet add package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli